# How to let tomcat 8.5 run on port 80 on AWS Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have been running Tomcat 7 on port 80 on AWS Linux. I run it as root and it has been working great. No issue.

Now, I have created a new AWS EC2 instance (t2.micro) using Linux 2 and I have installed java 11 and tomcat 8.5 on it. But I am not able to get tomcat to bind on port 80.  It runs fine on 8080 but not on 80. The error is

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
Mar 18 08:30:54 ----.compute.internal server[3467]: at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

What I have already done:

1. I have updated's tomcat's server.xml to use port 80 (changed 8080 to 80)
2. Tried running service as root: sudo tomcat start
3. Did "sudo su -" and then ran "tomcat start"
4. There was no TOMCAT_USER variable in tomcat.conf, so I added it
   TOMCAT_USER="root"
5. Tried running: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Can someone please tell me what do I need to do to fix it? I just need tomcat to be my webserver listening on 80 and 443. I don't want httpd, ngnix, or, port forwarding.

Here is the output of /etc/os-release:

```
 cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
[root@ip-172-31-32-37 ec2-user]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

Comment: Binding to port 80, requires `root`. Are you running your app as root?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, after logging in , i did sudo su - and then started tomcat server.
That is root, right?

Comment: Yes. So maybe you have something else listening on that port already?

Comment: That is not the case. I verified this as follows:
1. I wrote a socketserver in java that listens on port 80. I ran it as  $sudo java DumbSocketServer
It was able to bind to port and when I connected to it from my browser, it blurted out the request that it received.

So I know that it was able to bind.

2. But when I ran $sudo tomcat start it threw an exception while binding to 80.

Comment: OK, so this is what I did now:  I used wget to download latest tomcat and extracted it in my user directory /home/ec2-user/tomcat . Changed the port in server.xml to 80 and ran it using $sudo ./startup.sh  It worked!!!!
So, this is definitely something to do with how Amazon Linux installs tomcat. There is got to be some permission issue with the group or something.

Comment: Check what is this `tomcat` executable (it is not part of the Tomcat distribution). My guess is: it is a shell wrapper for calling SystemD. If it is, find the appropriate `*.service` file (look in `/lib/systemd`, `/usr/lib/systemd`, etc.) and add it to the question. Running on low port numbers requires the `CAP_NET_SERVICE_BIND` capability (`root` has all capabilities).